# Почему проект не видит android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Здравствуйте.

Хочу добавить к приложению возможность считывания информации с сенсоров телефона.

Сделал заготовку класса SensorActivity

```
package com.example.drno.android_app_1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.drno.android_app_1.R;

import static android.content.Context.SENSOR_SERVICE;

public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {

}
```

и снова обнаружилась проблема проект не видит классы **android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity**

Ранее эту проблему решал путем добавления в build.gradle зависимости

**compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0"**

В этом проекте не получилось, не могу понять почему...

[Ссылка на исходники проекта на GitHub](https://github.com/drno-reg/android_app_1.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` была [объявлена устаревшей](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LNyDnnBYJ8r) с библиотек поддержки версии 22.1.0 в пользу `AppCompatActivity`. Сейчас же упоминаний о `ActionBarActivity` в API нет вообще, видимо ее полностью выпилили. Сегодня нет никаких причин использовать этот класс в своих проектах.

PS: `ActionBarActivity` не мог находится в библиотеке поддержки core-utils